# Typescript and ASP.Net IScriptControl

Tags: asp.net, typescript, scriptmanager, microsoft-ajax, scriptcontrol

Is there a good way to write the javascript end of an ASP.Net IScriptControl (Microsoft Ajax) in Typescript?

The best I've found is https://github.com/chaholl/TypeScriptDefinitions/blob/master/MicrosoftAjax.d.ts - but that doesn't seem to be valid typescript (changes in the past year?) giving the warning warning *'declare' modifier required for top level element*

Comment: A grand total of three changes (two "declare" modifiers and one "boolean" instead of "bool") are required to make that file compile again. Be the pull request you want to see in the world.

Comment: There isn't one right now in the DefinitelyTyped project but I am working on it.  See Ryan's comment above too.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - as a complete new entrant to Typescript it's hard for me to work these things out - but yes, I will supply a pullrequest.

Comment: NYC - thanks. Is there anything I can help with?

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped and test it out when it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, there's now a typescript definition at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/microsoft-ajax

*Later...* The above link may now be dead, but a definition which appears to be by another author is available through [@types/microsoft-ajax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/microsoft-ajax).